# Selenium (python) : finding an element relative to a previously-found one

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm web-scrapping a page with the selenium module in python. I've looked for a certain element, and found it, like this:

```
drv = webdriver.Firefox(options=opt)
drv.get(url)
x = drv.find_element('xpath', './/div[@class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 guest-item "]')
```

Now I'd like to do a search for another element, using an XPath expression, but only inside the sub-tree that is below the `x` element, not across the entire document.

How can I specify that the XPath search should start from the `x` element and not from the document's root ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call the `find_element` method from the element *x*. For instance:

```
x.find_element('xpath', './/h2')
```

Comment: That was soo obvious :-( Why don't the docs show anything other than `driver.find_element` ?